# chef-solo nginx recipe not picking up on my attributes

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

the gist of my problem is located here:

https://gist.github.com/tsabat/a8f27ae6ac7d1fd3b6f7

The high-level problem is that chef-solo does not seem to pick up on attributes I set in my `attriutes/default.rb` file for a recipe.

I recently switched to chef 11 from 10 and I think that some breaking changes have me over a barrel.

Please help.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17679898/how-to-update-nginx-via-chef/17710858?noredirect=1#comment25813333_17710858). Your problem seems to be related to that one.

Comment: You are right, it has something to do with that.  I really did solve this by not depending on attributes in recipes, instead, I overrode my attributes in a role.

Comment: Oi. I've been running into this same issue for awhile, using chef-solo. Thanks for asking this.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override additional variables: `prefix`, `url`, `sbin_path` and `default_configure_flags`:

```
set['nginx']['version'] = "1.5.3"
set['nginx']['source']['version'] = "1.5.3"
# The Chef checksum of a binary is determined by: shasum -a 256 FILE_NAME
set['nginx']['source']['checksum'] = "edcdf2030750b4eb1ba8cd79365c16a3e33e6136b7fdd8a1a7b4082397f4e92b"
set['nginx']['source']['prefix'] = "/opt/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}"
set['nginx']['source']['url'] = "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-#{node['nginx']['source']['version']}.tar.gz"
set['nginx']['source']['sbin_path'] = "#{node['nginx']['source']['prefix']}/sbin/nginx"

set['nginx']['source']['default_configure_flags'] = [
  "--prefix=#{node['nginx']['source']['prefix']}",
  "--conf-path=#{node['nginx']['dir']}/nginx.conf",
  "--sbin-path=#{node['nginx']['source']['sbin_path']}"
]
```

This is because these variables embed other variables, and they are set using values that have not yet been overriden by your values.

By specifying these additional variables in your wrapper cookbook, you ensure they are using all the updated values you expect.

Also, because the `default` values are already set in the nginx cookbook, it's better to use something like `set` (an alias for `normal`) as that more accurately describes what you are doing and has a higher [attribute precedence](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#attribute-precedence).

Comment: Sure, I can do that. But, it seems overkill. I'd like to know why the variables that are derived fail to recognize that I've overridden ones they are derived from.

Answer (score 0):

Replied in your gist.

You need another default attribute "default['nginx']['version'] = 1.5.3" or it will override your compile flag `--prefix`.

Comment: Even with that attribute defined, I'm still getting the bad prefix. Check out the gist.

Comment: This really has something to do with the order of convergence and chef 11, because when I moved the attributes to a role, things started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So, I don't have an answer to why chef treats variables differently in recipes, but here is my fix.

Some change in the way attributes are picked up from a cookbook has me vexed.  Since I was using Chef Solo and it not supports roles, I just created a role, overrode the attributes there, and then called my base cookbook.

This model works more closely with how I conceptualize Chef when I'm working on the server, so it is a valid solution for me.  I did the following:

Create a role called Base

```
name "base"
description "The base role"
run_list "recipe[base]"
override_attributes "nginx" =>
  {
    'install_method' => 'source',
    'source' => {'version' => '1.5.3'}
  }
```

Add the role to the runlist via the Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = "vendor/cookbooks"
  chef.roles_path = "roles"
  chef.data_bags_path = "data_bags"
  chef.add_role "base"
end
```